# A function returning Result::Error will not revert the execution

Tags: ink, testing

I used the example `Flipper`, and changed the code like this:

```rs
#[ink(message)]
        pub fn flip(&mut self) -> Result<(), Error> {
            self.value = !self.value;
            return Err(Error::InsufficientAllowance);
        }
```

If I deployed the `contract` on chain, the function will not change the state `value`.

If I run `cargo test`, the state will be changed.

Answer (score 0):

It is the problem with Rust version. When I use 1.69.0, it works well.